# How to save a string to a json file

Tags: python, json

I want to save a string to a json file, but when I do it will write it with `\"` and with quotes at the beginning and at the end.

```py
import json

name_c = ['Don', 'Perez']

my_details = "data = {" + "\"name\": " + name_c[0] + ", \"lastname\": " + name_c[1] + "}"

print(my_details)

with open('personal.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(my_details, outfile)
```

I would like this kind of text in the json file:

```
data = {"name": Don, "lastname": Perez}
```

and I'm getting this kind of text in the json file

```
"data = {\"name\": Don, \"lastname\": Perez}"
```

Comment: I don't think that a string is valid `json`. You need to dump either a list or a dict.

Comment: That's because `my_details` is already a JSON string. By using JSON you're encoding that string to JSON again - so effectively double-encoding. The point of json.dumps is to allow you to automatically convert a python object to a JSON-formatted string. But since you already created a JSON string by hand in your code then you're not using it in the intended way.

Comment: And in general it's not a good idea to make JSON manually like that - it's very easy to get accidental syntax, quoting, escaping or encoding errors, either due to a mistake in the code or some unexpected values in the input data. The best practice is to create an object in your code which has the structure you need, and then use json.dumps to convert it to JSON in a reliable way.

Comment: @ADyson: Unfortunately, what OP wants written to the file is *not*, in a number of ways, JSON.

Comment: @quamrana: What the OP wants in the file isn't valid JSON, either.

Comment: @ScottHunter true, admitedly I didn't look as closely as I should have. But it appears to have been an attempt at a JSON string. The basic principle of my point still stands I think, but yes they need to do a bit more work (on both the input and the desired output)

Comment: @ScottHunter: Agree 100%

Comment: To reiterate, putting the `"data ="` before the JSON object means the file generated is not in valid [JSON format](http://json.org) (if that's your goal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why to not write string in file?

```
name_c = ['Don', 'Perez']
with open("out.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("data = {{\"name\": {}, \"lastname\": {}}}".format(*name_c))
```

If you want to use json, then smth like this:

```
name_c = ['Don', 'Perez']
with open("out.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("data = ")
    json.dump({"name": name_c[0], "lastname": name_c[1]}, f)
```

Or this:

```
name_c = ['Don', 'Perez']
with open("out.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("data = " + json.dumps({"name": name_c[0], "lastname": name_c[1]}))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is adding quotes because you are dumping a string; this is done regardless of what that string represents.  If you want it to dump an object, you have to give it an object to dump.